# Doom Emacs on Windows - Generating autoloads does not terminate when installing packages

Tags: emacs, autoload, elpa

I have a running Doom Emacs configuration on my Linux machine.
On my Windows machine I applied roughly the same config, which works for the most part.
But whenever I try to install packages using `install-package RET some-package-name RET` the process does not terminate and emacs freezes.
Waiting for some time fills up my ram.
The last message is `Generating autoloads for ~/.emacs.d/.local/elpa/...`, where ... is an `.el` file, sometimes it is the package I try to install, other times it is some other package.

So far, I had the same problem whatever package I tried to install.
Running `doom doctor` reveals no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Doom Emacs does not use the traditional `install-package`, but instead comes with its own package manager.

If you go to your Emacs config directory, then you should see a `packages.el` file and a `config.el` file.

The `package.el` specifies which packages to load, for instance

```
(package! org-auto-tangle)

(package! org-appear
  :recipe (:host github
           :repo "awth13/org-appear"))

(package! visual-fill-column)

(package! info-colors)
```

You then provide package-specific configuration in your `config.el`, for instance:

```
(use-package! org-auto-tangle
  :defer t
  :hook (org-mode . org-auto-tangle-mode)
  :config
  (setq org-auto-tangle-default t))

(add-hook! org-mode :append
           #'visual-line-mode
           #'variable-pitch-mode)
```

You need to run `doom sync` each time you made any modifications there.

Check out this section it the Getting Started Guide for more details: https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/blob/master/docs/getting_started.org#package-management

There is no `~/.emacs.d/.local/elpa/...` directory in Doom Emacs and according to the documentation linked above, manually installed packages will be forgotten when you restart Emacs and uninstalled next time you run `doom sync` or `doom purge`.

Comment: I suspect the hang that you’re getting is because Doom Emacs overrides some of the package loading logic - to make it work with it’s setup - and when you try the old `package-install, that might get confused somehow.  Try the recommended installation that I described above and see whether that fixes it for you.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know doom would forget the packages installed via `package-install`. I always installed the package via the command first and then add it to `package.el`. Do you have any idea why this problem only occurs on Windows and not on Linux?